# 2D collision detection of images with transparent parts ignored

Tags: java, 2d, transparency, collision-detection

So I decided to look up some collision detection but I've been having trouble finding proper information
regarding 2d collision detection between two images that includes how to properly avoid detecting the transparent
areas of an image but I did find one post which I got myself attached to but the problem is that I don't
really understand the post nor do I understand why he does some of those things...

Here's the post in question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/336615/revisions

So first of all I want to ask if this solution is actually a good one / proper or if I should just look elsewhere.

Secondly I wonder, in his post, he mentions using integer arrays, not 2d arrays either it seems,  to
set 1 and 0 to decide  whether or not the pixel is transparent or not but I don't really know how I am supposed
to achieve this. At first I thought it could be achieved by just forming a string of 1 and 0s and convert it to a Long
but even with a mere image width of 25, the Long, gets... too long...

I also tried this with no luck, since the code does not function with this array:

```
 long[] array = new long[30*30]; // height * width of the image
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<30*30; i++){
    if(image.getRGB(x,y) == 0){
         array[i] = 0;
    }
    else{ array[i] = 1; }

    x++;
    if (x==30){
         y++;
         x=0;
    } 
}
```

Thirdly, I was hoping someone could maybe explain the whole process and why the things he does, are necessary.
By the way, I do know how those bit wise operators work! 
In other words, I don't understand his train of thought / motivation for doing the all things in the code and I would like to gain an understanding of all this!

I don't really know how to proceed right now hehe...

Comment: Unless you have very specific requirements (for example, having very irregular shapes that can't be easily described using primitives), testing collisions with collision geometry is faster, more straight forward and more likely to produce useful results. " Secondly I wonder, in his post, he mentions using integer arrays, not 2d arrays either it seems" You can use one dimensional arrays to represent two dimensional data: int arr[H][W] => int arr[H*W], arr[y][x] => arr[y*W+x].

Comment: What is collision geometry? Googling don't give very much!

Even so, I'd still like to understand the code. I tried to fill up an array[h*x] with 1 and 0s but when implemented in the code given it's not working. I'm really trying to understand the code but I don't understand his process / motivation for the stuff he does at all and I've tried to figure it out but no luck!

Comment: What he's doing is checking collision with a bitmask. (google should yield relevant results). Collision geometry is just geometry really - instead of thinking "do these two images collide" think "do these rectangles/triangles/circles/any combination of those collide". The advantage is that this is faster (for example, two 2D circles collide if their distance is smaller than the sum of their radii) than using bitmasks, and also yields results like "what is the smallest shift I have to apply to this object so it doesn't collide anymore". Look into separating axis theorem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the [bitwise AND operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (`&`) is true (1) for each each bit where the the corresponding bit is true in both operands, and false (0) otherwise.

The idea he's using is to create a version of the image (a mask) where each non-transparent pixel in the original image is stored as a '1' bit, and each transparent pixel as a '0' bit. These are packed into a single integer, which can be tested against the mask for another image with a single AND operation (before the AND he calculates the horizontal distance between the two images and shifts one of the masks if necessary).

For example, let's assume that we have the following two 4x1 pixel images:

```
5, 0, 0, 5
      8, 8, 8, 8
```

Although I placed them on separate rows here for practical purposes, you should view them as being on the same row, so the last two pixels of the left image overlap with the first two of the right image.

The masks for the rows when viewed in binary representation would be:

```
1001
1111
```

The distance between the left and right image is -2, so we shift the first mask left by 2 bits:

```
1001 << 2 => 100100
```

So now we have these masks:

```
100100
001111
```

ANDing these gives us:

```
000100
```

The non-zero result tells us that we have a collision.